# How to get the last inserted row of a group of rows matching some criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing a problem of getting the last inserted row of group of rows in a table with GUID id

```
select * from Students where StudentName like 'fares'
```

If I got two rows as a result how to get the most recently inserted row of these two rows?

It doesn't matter if the solution with SQL or TSQL or EntityFramework

thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have a date/timestamp, or an ever-increasing key of some sorts, this is impossible to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a monotonically increasing column to sort by then order by that. There is no way of doing this otherwise.

SQL Server does not preserve any information in the data pages about order rows are inserted that you can leverage.

Comment: +1 must have some kind of an ever-increasing ID or a date/time stamp to go on.

Comment: i thought that maybe there is something like rowid thanx anyway that helped

Comment: There is a type Called Timestamp in the SQL server 2008 isn't it a good choice?

Comment: @major - `Timestamp` is a synonym for `rowversion`. This is nothing to do with datetime but is a `binary(8)` counter column that SQL Server automatically updates both at `insert` **and at update** so this wouldn't help you with knowing most recently **inserted**.

Comment: @martin thank you for that too i was going to use **timestamp** before you tell me this information.